# Certain text in wrong font and misaligned in Google Chrome

Tags: kde, fonts, chrome, kde5

I'm running Google Chrome on Arch Linux with KDE 5. Just yesterday, Chrome's tab text, omnibox text, and bookmark bar text switched to a different font; the tab and omnibox text also became misaligned vertically. I tried changing both KDE's and Chrome's default fonts, but the text in question respects neither. Clearing `.config/google-chrome` and reinstalling Chrome did nothing. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was suggested by "achillion" on Arch's IRC channel:

You should check GTK's font and theme settings by launching the KDE GTK configurator with this command: `kcmshell5 kde-gtk-config`.

You must also install the configurator by installing the `extra/kde-gtk-config` package.

Relaunch Google Chrome after saving your changes in the configurator.